# Bayesian network probabilities

Tags: networking, bayesian

I don't really know if that is appropriate here but I have a mathematical problem linked to IA to solve and it sounds easy but I have issues to do it.
Basically, I'm working on Bayesian Networks and here are the definitions that the teacher gave us:

[image: Definitions]

The idea is to do the exercice.
I went off with a reccurence on n the number of elements of V (because this is what the teacher suggested) and I managed to do the initialization but I'm struggling with the reccurence itself.
Would anyone know possibly how to solve this?
Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Quickly, it is sufficient to note that a DAG has at least one leaf F and that such a leaf only appears in one term of the factorization of the joint probability distribution : P(F|parents(F)).

We can therefore isolate sum_F P(F|parents(F)) and this necessarily sums to 1. What remains is a DAG on all variables except F with the same kind of decomposition for its joint distribution.  So recursively ...